# How to Perform remote build in Jenkins

Tags: build, jenkins, remote-server

I am new to Jenkins. Please help me with my requirement.

I'm running Jenkins in Windows environment. I have a development box where Jenkins is running successfully. Now, I have to do a build in another windows machine (say QA box) from the dev box. Can anyone suggest me please how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Solution is quite simple.

**Step 1**: Create and configure the slave node (QA BOX) with Jenkins.

- Goto Manage Jenkins
- Click on Manage Nodes
- New Node Configuration

**Step 2**: There may be several ways to complete this task.
**Configure the jobs according to the new machine (IP, Ports or any other dependencies).** A good practice is keeping the build scripts separate for machine or keeping the separate properties files for different machines.

- Configuer Jobs According to the new slave configuration.
- Keep in mind any dependency over File Structure, IPs and Ports.

**Step 3**: Run the jobs and debug for any dependencies regarding the machine.

- If you encounter any trouble. Go through the logs and find the related problem.

Comment: Thanks Aura.... I got it working. Now, I have more tasks. The build will be done in Dev box. I have to take that build and deploy in the QA box. Jboss server is running in the QA box. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Take all files (Meaning compile, generate code, package, etc.) put them in your workspace and write scripts for their deployment over the QA BOX machine. Keep your workspace updated. It will be a good practice if you can keep your workspace in a SVN Repo.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a test node for your QA BOX
2. Configure a Job to:

   - Update the latest code to the remote test node, example SVN
   - Configure the build setting for the remote test node build, example using ANT
3. Done